# Django POST data dictionary is empty when posting from test client

Tags: ajax, django, testing

I am trying to test and AJAX view in my Django Project. When submit the post from JQuery the data is correctly accessible in the Django View but when I try to make queries for the Django test client it is emplty.

Here is the code I use:

**The view**

```
def add_item(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':

        post_data = request.POST
        print post_data   ## <----- THIS IS EMPTY

        name = post_data.get('name')

        # Render the succes response
        json_data = json.dumps({"success":1})
        return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type="application/json")
else:
    raise Http404
```

**And the test**

```
class TestAddItem(TestCase):  
    def test_some_test(self):
        data = {
        'description':"description",      
        }

        response = self.client.post('theurl', data, content_type='application/json')
```

Any Idea what I might be doing wrong?
I tried also without content type and also using plain url like `thurl/?name=name` without succes.
Any help will be appreciated.

Olivier

Answer (score 1):

After trying different combinations of parameter formating, content types, etc..
I found one solution that works :

```
response = self.client.post(reverse('theurl'), data, 
             **{'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH': 'XMLHttpRequest'})
```

And I get the following dictionary on the POST parameters of the request:

```
<QueryDict: {u'name': [u'name']}>
```

**Edit** I love testing :)