# Django test client post data is empty

Tags: django, testing, client

I have a very simply application where I have to create a simple post request using a django test client.

```
userFrom = Client()
userFrom.login(username="admin1",password=test_password)
data = {"some":"data"}
responseNew = userFrom.post("/foo/too/",simplejson.dumps(data),content_type="application/json")
```

When I check the post request at the view of "/foo/too/" the post dictionary is empty.

I have checked the following question. It does not work.
I am using Django 1.5.

[Post dictionary is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22580226/django-post-data-dictionary-is-empty-when-posting-from-test-client)

Comment: Try `userFrom.post("/foo/too/",data)` if it works

Comment: If you want to accept json data, you'll probably have to read from `request.body`. Django Rest Framework has utilities to do this automatically for you if you are writing an API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
responseNew = userFrom.post("/foo/too/", data)
```

Comment: After hours of searching this is the right answer. If you define content_type or format it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

If post data is still empty try to send json

```
client.post(url, json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: This got it working for me. I think this must be a bug, since [the docs say](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.post) _"If you provide content_type as application/json, the data is serialized using json.dumps() if it’s a dict, list, or tuple."_

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me.

Post your data as-is, setting `content_type` to `"application/json"`:

```
response = user.post("/foo/too/", data, content_type="application/json")
```

Then in your view, read the data from `request.body` like this:

```
data = json.loads(request.body)
```